# Difference between @Path and @WebServlet

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, servlets

In Java EE I notice that you can specify a path to a uri either as

```
@Path("/SomePath")
public class MyClass
```

or

```
@WebServlet("/SomePath")
public class MyClass extends HttpServlet
```

I think @Path is used for non-servlet stuff while @WebServlet is used for servlets. But do they effectively serve the same purpose?

Info on @Path can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp26/index.html

But at first glance, it seems to provide some of the basic functionality as @WebServlet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@Path` annotation defines a path to a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) Web service so when you have `@Path("/SomeService")` it will translate into `www.yourapp.com/baseRestUrl/SomeService`. You can also define it on the methods which provides REST services. Note that `baseRestUrl` is defined inside `web.xml` or in class which extends `Application` class.

On the other hand `@WebServlet("/SomePath")` states that [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) will be listening for request on the `www.yourapp.com/SomePath`, it is basically replacement of `servlet-mapping` element in `web.xml`. You can still configure servlets like this, it's up to you whether you prefer XML or annotation configuration.

Comment: But I use @WebServlet for RESTful services, so I don't see your point.

Comment: Of course you can do that but I don't think this is a good idea, you have to implement lot of stuff on your own (which is error prone) - if I were you, I would definitely write REST services with Java REST API and not hacking it through servlets.

Answer (score 0):

The @Path annotation identifies the URI path template to which the resource responds and is specified at the class or method level of a resource. The @Path annotation’s value is a partial URI path template relative to the base URI of the server on which the resource is deployed, the context root of the application, and the URL pattern to which the JAX-RS runtime responds.

The @WebServlet annotation is used to declare a servlet. The annotated class must extend the javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet class.